# DBunit insert xml despite exception

Tags: java, xml, exception, dbunit, continue

I'm trying to use DBunit for a project. 
For this project, I'm trying to insert a large quantity of data from a XML file with :

```
DatabaseOperation.INSERT.execute(conn, new FlatXmlDataSet(new File(file)));
```

The problem is when I've got an exception (SQLException), the insert operation stops and the rest of the data is not inserted. I'm looking for a way to continue inserting despite exception, but nothing so far.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to do:

```
DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(conn, new FlatXmlDataSet(new File(file)));
```

This is because if you only do DatabaseOperation.INSERT and the data you want to insert exists in the DB the operation will fail. In this way the operation first will delete all table records and then will do the insert.

Moreover, in you xml file tables must be in the insert correct order to avoid 
integrity constraints errors.

To read xml file:

```
FlatXmlDataSetBuilder flatXmlDataSetBuilder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("XMLpath");
IDataSet iDataSet = flatXmlDataSetBuilder.build(fileInputStream);
DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(conn, iDataset);
```